# Cookies and Jar Problem

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

**STATEMENT**
Bowl 1 contains 30 vanilla cookies and 10 chocolate cookies. Bowl 2 contains 20 of each. Now suppose you choose one of the bowls at random and, without looking, choose a cookie at random. The cookie is vanilla. What is the  Probability that it came from Bowl 1?

$P(\text {choosing Bowl 1}) = \frac 12$

$P(\text {choosing a vanilla cookie from Bowl 1}) = \frac {30}{40}$

Since events are independent, $ = \frac 12 \times \frac {30}{40} = \frac 38$  .. and this answer is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good example of Bayes Rule:
$$P(B_1|V)=\frac{P(V|B_1)P(B_1)}{P(V)}$$

Your calculation gives $P(V|B_1)P(B_1)=P(B_1\cap V)$, but the denominator needs to be calculated as well:

$$P(V)=P(V|B_1)P(B_1)+P(V|B_2)P(B_2)$$

**A toy example**: Bowl 1 contains 1 vanilla, Bowl 2 contains 1 chocolate. Say, we select a random bowl and select a random cookie. If the chosen cookie, is vanilla, what is the probability that it's chosen from Bowl 1?

Your way gives $1/2\times1=1/2$, but actually it's certain, i.e. probability is 1, that the cookie is from Bowl 1. Keep in mind that what you're asked is $P(B_1|V)$, not $P(B_1\cap V)$.

**Note**: $V|B_1$ is not an event. This notation makes sense inside $P(.)$ expression. So, you should define your events carefully and express the question in terms of these events.

Comment: I could have calculated it using Baye's Theorem. Even the denominator can be expanded to:  $P(A) = P(A|B)P(B) + P(A|B^c)P(B^c)$

But the point is which part of the statement  shows they are dependent events?

Comment: The probability you're asked is $P(B_1|V)$. But, you're calculating $P(B_1\cap V)$. So, multiplying them ($P(V|B_1)$ and $P(B_1)$) will not give you what is asked on the question. It's not a dependence/independence issue.

Comment: So, conditional probability can be applied to independent events?

Comment: I can't follow you. What does 'applying conditional probability' mean?

Comment: Baye's theorem is used/applied when one event is affecting the other.  If P(A | B) = P(A), then events A and B are said to be "independent", which seems to be the case here.

Comment: You can apply Bayes theorem any time. If the events are independent, applying Bayes theorem gives you $P(A|B)=P(A)$ already.

Comment: Exactly. Then as per Baye's theorem, if P(A|B)=P(A) then B is not affecting A. So in this case here too both jars have equal probabilities of 1/2 to be chosen, that ain't affected by anything.

Comment: Ok, let me be clearer: The second probability you give is $P(V|B_1)$, which means Bowl 1 is already chosen, so it's on the given side. $V|B_1$ is not an event. The given sign doesn't make any sense in set notation. It makes sense inside the probability expression. Here, $V$ and $B_1$ are your events. And, you need to formulate the question in terms of these events. 

For example, how can you formulate "What is the Probability that it came from Bowl 1" based on your event definitions? Why are you multiplying them? What does $(V|B_1)\cap V$ mean (it doesn't actually, but acc. to you it means)?

Comment: Yes,  V and B1 are the events and since they are independent, hence their probabilities can be multiplied.  

(V|B1)∩V  is a mixture of set theory and Probability notation.  It is like  $A^c = 1 - P(A)$ which actually doesn't mean anything because we have to map set-theory to Probability, all of it, hence the correct notation will be $P(A^c) = 1 - P(A)$. For your case  it should be  $B1 \cap V$ or $V \cap V$

Comment: $V$ and $B_1$ are not independent. The odds of choosing a vanilla cookie depends on what bowl chosen.

Comment: So, if we choose B1 then there is is higher probability of getting vanilla cookies compared to choosing B2. Is this what we call dependence?

Comment: Yes, that's the logic.

Comment: @Arnuld is it clear now?

Comment: yeah, understood. Thanks man :-) . For independent events, we can simply multiply the probabilities, but for dependent events, we need to use Baye's Theorem to get the probabilities right